# Show results of multiple prompt boxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make multiple prompt boxes and sort their input alphabetically and then show on screen using JavaScript ?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what effort have you done? to me, this reads as homework.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Try: loop, array, [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), DOM

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Sequentially**

if you are talking about the almost obsolete native javascrtipt function `prompt()` then:

```
var array=[];questions=['A?','B?','C?'],current=0;
function q(question){
 array.push(prompt(question,'write here')+' question number:'+current);
 if(current<questions.length){
  next()
 }else{
  array.sort()// needs a proper sort function
  alert(array.join("\n"));
 };
}
function next(){
 q(questions[current++]);
}
next();
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/c7GnX/